# SQL:selecting top record for a group of column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select top record with max value for a group of other columns. In the sample data below, i need to select top record with max 'Weightage' for each group of 'id', 'ItemType'

```
 create table sampleTable(id int, ItemType varchar(10), ItemCode varchar(10), Weightage int)
insert into sampleTable values(1, 'A','aaa',2)
 insert into sampleTable values(1, 'A','bbb',3)
insert into sampleTable values(1, 'A','ccc',3)
insert into sampleTable values(1, 'B','ddd',1)
insert into sampleTable values(1, 'B','eee',2)
insert into sampleTable values(2, 'A','aaa',1)
```

The expected output should be

```
id          ItemType    ItemCode
 --------------------------------
 1          A           bbb
1           B           eee
2           A           aaa
```

I tried as follows

```
SELECT top 1 id, ItemType,ItemCode
FROM sampleTable  WITH(NOLOCK)  
GROUP BY id,ItemType,ItemCode,Weightage
ORDER BY Weightage desc
```

But it is not giving expected result. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way using `ROW_NUMBER`

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH ties id, 
                       itemtype, 
                       itemcode 
FROM   sampletable WITH(nolock) 
GROUP  BY id, 
          itemtype, 
          itemcode, 
          weightage 
ORDER  BY Row_number()OVER(partition BY id, itemtype ORDER BY weightage DESC)
```

`TOP 1 with TIES` will return the records with Tie based on `Order by`

Hope you know the meaning of using `WITH(NOLOCK)` *hint*. It will pull uncommitted data as well

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option using `row_number()`:

```
select * 
from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by id, itemtype order by Weightage desc) rn
    from sampletable
) t
where rn = 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f623d/1)